# Was the Oceanic flight 815 pilot the only one attacked by the monster?

Tags: lost

So, after several years and having exhausted most of the good material on Netflix. I've started watching Lost again. If I remember correctly, the monster didn't actually attack anyone in the series, so I was a little shock to see that it pulled the pilot out of the plane in the pilot episode. Was anyone else actually attacked by the smoke monster, or is this just an example of [early installment weirdness?](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EarlyInstallmentWeirdness)

Comment: The Smoke Monster attacks several people throughout the series.

Comment: I guess it's entirely possible I could just be strongly mis-remembering. There are too many moving parts in lost.

Comment: Could have been answered by continuing to watch the show :P

Comment: While I can't argue that, I can definitely say I would have forgotten the question a few seasons in. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, there are several other attacks.  Here's some of the more memorable ones:

- Locke is nearly dragged underground - or into a lethal fall into a hole, hard to tell - by the creature before Jack sends some dynamite down the hole.  In fact, this is probably the incident that confirms it as a "smoke" monster.
- Mr. Eko, shortly after refusing to be manipulated by the visions the creature has given him, is beaten to death by an enraged smoke monster.
- It tries to go after Kate and Juliet, but Juliet gets them both behind some protection before it can do much.
- It goes on a rampage against the military team trying to kill Linus, but it does so at Linus' direction.
- It also tears apart a temple maintained by the Others sometime in the last season.
- In flashback to Richard's distant arrival on the island, the slaver ship Black Rock is washed ashore and its crew are slaughtered en masse by the smoke monster, just after they in turn were slaughtering the slaves, and saving Richard from his turn by a hair so that he can be used (courtesy comment from @Lightness Races in Orbit).

Comment: Don't forget the Black Rock crew. Yeah it like literally kills scores of people. Maybe even hundreds.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - got it, added.  My memory of *Lost* has gotten fuzzy over the years, and I haven't had a good enough reason to rewatch it.

Comment: I love how nobody ever interpreted "smoke monster" as "demon", until literally the final season when we found out it's intelligent.

Comment: There was also the French expedition. Nadine was killed and Montand had his arm severed.

Comment: He's also capable of killing the player character in *Lost: Via Domus*, though it isn't canon.